# In "the chickens come home to roost" - is "roost" a verb or noun?

Tags: idioms

Consider:

> the chickens come home to roost

Is the word *roost* used as a verb or noun in this idiom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this idiom, it is a verb. *(infinitive phrase)* and gives the reason the chickens have returned.  The noun form would be:

*"The chickens have come home to their roost."*